# How to have the compiler put a header file in a source file

Tags: c, gcc, header-files

I know you can put a header file on top of a file by using the `-include` compiler flag in gcc, but is it possible to include the header file at the end of other header file declarations of a file. So for example, I have the following declarations in a C source file.

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
```

I would like it, to become

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
#include "inserted.h"
```

rather than

```
#include "inserted.h"
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
```

Comment: Why would you (ever) want to do this?

Comment: @unwind - So that the source files are left untouched.

Comment: Why do you need to leave the source files untouched? How would adding `#include "inserted.h"` not solve your problem? See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: `sed` or `awk` and compiling from the standard input could do it too, if you're really set on it.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
-include a.h -include b.h -include inserted.h
```

Add header protection to all `*.h` files (which should be there anyway ... ;-).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do exactly what you are asking. There is no way to tell the compiler to insert a header file at a random point in a file. But maybe you can get something close.

First make all the declarations in inserted.h as a macro:

```
#define DECLARE_INSERTED_H \
    int gFoo = 0;          \
    void functionBar();    \
```

Then in your c file:

```
#include a.h
#include b.h

#ifndef DECLARE_INSERTED_H
#define DECLARE_INSERTED_H
#endif // !DECLARE_INSERTED_H

DECLARE_INSERTED_H
```

Then compile with -i inserted.h